# Printing data type char with printf()

Tags: c, format, printf

The `printf()` function uses the format specifier `%s` to print `char *`.
The standard does not specify how `char` is implemented as signed or unsigned.

So when `char` is implemented as signed `char`, and we use `%s` to print `unsigned char *`, is it safe to do this?

Which format specifier should we use in this case?

Comment: Pointers don't have signs, and the pointer target is not handled arithmetically, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MartinJames Unclear how the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426473/printing-data-type-char-with-printf/46427667#comment79809984_46426473) applies here.  Perhaps it reflects an earlier version of the question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... when `char` is implemented in `signed char`, and we use `"%s"` to print `unsigned char*`.  Is it safe to do this?

Yes it is safe.

```
char *cp = ...;
signed char *scp = ...;
unsigned char *ucp = ...;
printf("%s", cp);  // OK.
printf("%s", scp);  // OK.
printf("%s", ucp);  // OK.
```

> (%s) ...  the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. ... C11dr §7.21.6.1 8
>
> The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*.  C11 §6.2.5 15

Comment: Thank you ! I have read the standard, and see the %s need character type, but I haven't gotten what character type is. I should read the standard more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 char name[]="siva";
 printf("name = %p\n", name);
 printf("&name[0] = %p\n", &name[0]);
 printf("name printed as %%s is %s\n",name);
 printf("*name = %c\n",*name);
 printf("name[0] = %c\n", name[0]);
}
```

Output is:

```
name = 0xbff5391b  
&name[0] = 0xbff5391b
name printed as %s is siva
*name = s
name[0] = s
```

So 'name' is actually a pointer to the array of characters in memory.